# how combine multiple rows into a single row in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How can i do below in oracle?

**input**

```
id units  unit_description
12  20     kWh
12  50     kWh
12  100    days
15  80     kWh
```

I want merged in column 2  and 3 based on column 1 into one single row. And the result should be like

**output:**

```
id  | unit details
12 70 KWh , 100 days
15 80 KWh
```

Comment: What have you done so far? You can start with learning group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below query. Mostly it should work in your case. It may not execute at once, modify as per your requirement.

```
SELECT id,
         LISTAGG (unit || ' ' || unit_description, ', ')
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY unit, unit_description)
    FROM (  SELECT id, unit_description, SUM (unit) AS unit
              FROM table1
          GROUP BY id, unit_description)
GROUP BY id;
```